# How to run connectedCheck test command for debug build type and build flavor?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, uitest, android-build-type

I run the `connectedCheck` command to execute my tests on the device and everything works well.
But when I use `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` in debug build type the `connectedCheck` command does not run any test on my device, Why?
How do I config this?

```
debug{
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    versionNameSuffix '.debug'
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
    debuggable true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by add ".debug" at the end of my packagename in gradle:

myPackageName.debug.cucumber.runner.CucumberTestRunner

and

glue = ["myPackageName.debug.cucumber.steps"] in @CucumberOptions

But it does not work for my build flavors yet ...!
What should be the proper command "connectedCheck" and the name of the packages for any flavor so that my UI test can work?